Ubuntu 24.04 System Instability After BIOS Update: Random reboots
I’ve been experiencing significant system instability on my Ubuntu 24.04 machine after a recent BIOS update. The system randomly resets itself, and the logs show various errors. I’m hoping to get some guidance on how to troubleshoot and resolve these issues.
System Information:

OS: Ubuntu 24.04 (Previously Ubuntu 22.04 with the same issue)
Kernel: 6.8.0-40-generic
Motherboard: Gigabyte Z790 GAMING X AX DDR5 LGA1700 (Rev 1.1)
CPU: Intel i7-13700k
BIOS Version: Updated to F11d (latest) from Gigabyte’s website due to issues with microcode for 13th and 14th generation Intel processors. The problem started after updating to F11c, and F11d did not resolve it.
Dual Boot: Windows and Ubuntu (Issue does not appear on Windows, at least not yet)

Issue Description:
Since updating the BIOS, my system has been crashing randomly, and the logs are filled with various errors. I’ve tried resetting the BIOS to its default settings, but the issue persists. The crashes occur at random moments, even when the system is idle, with no applications running. Here’s a snapshot of the errors occurring shortly after boot:
$journalctl --since "2024-08-14 12:15:00" --until "2024-08-14 12:34:00" -p 0..3                                     

sie 14 12:16:17 BMO kernel: i2c i2c-1: Invalid 7-bit I2C address 0xffff
sie 14 12:16:18 BMO kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Invalid buffer destination
sie 14 12:16:18 BMO kernel: 
sie 14 12:16:19 BMO kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Malformed MSFT vendor event: 0x02
sie 14 12:16:19 BMO bluetoothd[1234]: profiles/sap/server.c:sap_server_register() Sap driver initialization failed.
sie 14 12:16:19 BMO bluetoothd[1234]: sap-server: Operation not permitted (1)
sie 14 12:16:29 BMO gdm-password][2251]: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
sie 14 12:16:32 BMO systemd[2295]: Failed to start app-gnome-gnome\x2dkeyring\x2dpkcs11-2688.scope - Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
sie 14 12:16:32 BMO systemd[2295]: Failed to start app-gnome-gnome\x2dkeyring\x2dsecrets-2685.scope - Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
sie 14 12:16:32 BMO systemd[2295]: Failed to start app-gnome-gnome\x2dkeyring\x2dssh-2682.scope - Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
sie 14 12:16:32 BMO systemd[2295]: Failed to start app-gnome-snap\x2duserd\x2dautostart-2942.scope - Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
sie 14 12:16:32 BMO systemd[2295]: Failed to start app-gnome-user\x2ddirs\x2dupdate\x2dgtk-2950.scope - Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
sie 14 12:16:33 BMO kernel: [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
sie 14 12:16:33 BMO kernel: [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
sie 14 12:16:33 BMO kernel: [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
sie 14 12:16:33 BMO kernel: [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
sie 14 12:16:33 BMO kernel: [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
sie 14 12:16:33 BMO kernel: [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
sie 14 12:16:33 BMO kernel: [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
sie 14 12:16:33 BMO kernel: [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
sie 14 12:16:33 BMO kernel: [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership

Troubleshooting Steps Taken So Far:

I2C: Running i2cdetect -y -r 1 shows a device at address 0x48, but the Invalid 7-bit I2C address 0xffff error persists.

sudo i2cdetect -y -r 1
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:                         -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 48 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 


WiFi: The Intel WiFi card (iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Invalid buffer destination) continues to show errors even with updated drivers.
Bluetooth: Reinstalling bluez did not resolve the Bluetooth errors related to malformed MSFT vendor events.
GNOME Keyring: Multiple GNOME Keyring components fail to start, affecting other system processes.
NVIDIA DRM: The DRM module for NVIDIA (nv_drm_master_set) fails to grab modeset ownership, potentially causing graphical instability.
Memtest86+: Passed without errors, so RAM issues are unlikely.
Temperatures: I’ve been monitoring component temperatures closely, and none of them appear to be overheating.

Additional Information:

Dual Boot: I have a dual-boot setup with Windows, and this issue does not occur on Windows (at least, not yet).
BIOS Reset: I’ve reset the BIOS to its default settings, but the issue persists.
Random Ubuntu reboots: The system reboot itself randomly, even when idle with no applications running.
Previous Ubuntu Version: The problem started on Ubuntu 22.04 after the BIOS update, so I reinstall to Ubuntu 24.04, but the issue remains.

Request for Help:
I’m looking for:

Guidance on identifying which of these errors might be causing the system resets.
Could the BIOS update have introduced hardware or firmware incompatibilities with the current Ubuntu kernel?
What steps can I take to isolate whether this is a hardware or software issue?

Has anyone encountered similar issues post-BIOS update, and if so, how were they resolved? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you in advance!

So you believe that the BIOS update caused the issue. If that is the case, then are you in a position to fix bugs in the BIOS? I suggest that's unlikely. Reverting to previous BIOS verion would a) confirm the cause of the problem b) give you a stable system, but do report the issue to the vendor.

The problem occurs exclusively on Ubuntu, so I assumed it should be solvable from the Ubuntu level, which does a system reboot for a good reason. I assume that if I find the cause, I'll be able to solve it without rolling back the bios version (because then the 13th generation Intel processor problem will still remain, and I'd rather avoid that). I also don't want to give up on Ubuntu, so I assume that somewhere there is probably a solution to this problem on the Ubuntu side.

I've been trying to troubleshoot a similar issue here. I'm writing here because your problem looks sufficiently close to mine, and I may have found a solution ("may" because you can never be sure of a random reboot not happening). However, please do note the differences in our systems below.
System Information

OS: EndeavourOS (Installer ISO from 2024.06.25)
Kernel: from 6.10.3-arch1-2 to 6.10.8-arch1-1
Motherboard: Gigabyte Z790 Gaming X AX (Rev. 1.1)
BIOS Version: F11c, F11d
CPU: Intel i5-13600K
Dual Boot: No Windows
Memory: Patriot Viper Venom 2x32GB DDR5-5200 CL40
New desktop with all parts new

Symptoms

The system just shuts off at an instance and immediately reboots at random times. It would usually happen several hours after the system startup, but I've also seen 4 minutes and 17 hours.
The system journal for the last session (where the reboot happened) does not show useful information on what happened before the reboot.
The system journal shows the same error messages about I2C address, wifi WRT buffer, and Bluetooth MSFT at system startup. I don't have GNOME Keyring installed, and my NVIDIA module doesn't report any errors. (I'm actually not sure if these errors are related to the reboots, though.)
I'm always monitoring the system with btop, and everything looks fine including the temperatures.
Stress tests like memtest86+, stress, vkmark, and mprime run fine for extended periods of time. The reboots only happen when the system is mostly idling.
The reboots have happened on: installer ISO, btrfs, ext4.
The reboots have happened in: tty, KDE, Hyprland, river.

What worked
Disable some of higher c-states. Some ways to do it:

Add intel_idle.max_cstate=<number> to kernel boot parameter. The value for <number> should be an integer from 0 to 9.
Disable some c-states in the motherboard's BIOS settings. In the advanced settings page, select Tweaks > Advanced CPU Settings > C State Control. When you change it to Enabled, more options will appear right below.

The safe limit I found is up to C7. That means either:

setting boot parameter intel_idle.max_cstate=7; or
configuring the BIOS options:

C8 State Support: Disabled
C10 State Support: Disabled
Package C State Limit: C7s



Since you're dual-booting with Windows, I suggest the first method (kernel boot parameter). This is because restricting higher C-states basically prevents the CPU from going into more power-saving states when there is little work to do. Since everything works fine on Windows, it's better to allow all C-states there.
Why Is This Happening?
While I don't have a definitive answer, I have a speculation that I feel confident enough to share at this point. It looks like an issue with the motherboard's firmware because:

I've tried tweaking various options in the motherboard's BIOS settings including CPU features and voltages, but none of them worked other than directly disabling the c-states;
I've also tried different kernel parameters related to power management but haven't found anything that worked other than restricting c-states;
I installed Windows myself and checked that the reboots don't happen there (although it did happen once before connecting to the internet and getting updates and drivers);
the BIOS versions we have are beta versions;
some posts and comments on r/gigabyte subreddit mentioned that Intel might distribute another microcode update late this month which is said to be a "proper" fix for the excessive voltage problem, and Gigabyte might upload the "proper" BIOS version with the fix after that; and
I came across this page on Arch Linux wiki where I learned it's possible some motherboards' firmware have malformed (or only-made-and-tested-for-Windows) ACPI tables and the users can try to patch it if needed, which I think could also be the reason my desktop fails to suspend to RAM, but I digress.

So basically, assuming that I'm blaming the right thing, the motherboard firmware provided by Gigabyte is borked for Linux. But like I said, I don't have any proof or evidence, so please don't take this as the truth. I could try decompiling and looking into the ACPI tables in the firmware, but I've already spent too much time on this issue. Though, I might do that if the next BIOS version also shows the same problem...

Thanks a lot - there's nothing left to do but try it and see if it actually brings the desired result

@Terixer Have you managed to check if it works for your desktop? I updated the answer with some new information I got. Please feel free to ask me if you have any questions.

Thanks in advance for your answer!

what will be the negative consequences of disabling higher states of C? Won't it destroy my processor?
why is it exactly that Linux can't handle it?
and will not adding only the parameter “intel_idle.max_cstate=3” solve the problem if the problem is only on Linux? Do you actually have to disable it from the bios level?


@Terixer 1. Higher C-states allow the CPU cores to go into deeper sleeping states when there is no work to do (e.g., waiting for network packets, disk read/write, or mouse/keyboard inputs). If you want a bit more detail, this short section on Wikipedia seems good (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACPI#Processor_states). Disabling higher C-states would slightly increase the power consumption, but it won't be too much of a problem. CPU frequencies are handled by a different thing called P-states, and that's only applicable for C0 state.

@Terixer 2. I've heard that a lot of desktop hardware firmwares are only tested with latest Windows versions. I don't know if that claim is factually accurate, but it's true that a lot of Linux users have been facing issues with buggy firmwares from time to time. This is just my guess, but it could be that Linux drivers have to be reverse-engineered a lot of times whereas Windows drivers are typically provided by the hardware manufacturers. Even if the firmware somewhat diverges from the known standards like ACPI, it wouldn't matter on Windows if their driver makes up for that.

@Terixer 3. Yes, only adding that boot parameter will work and would actually be better for you since you also boot into Windows. It's just that I personally haven't tested the boot parameter method other than value 1. Since I don't dual boot, changing the boot parameter was more cumbersome while trying out different values. Btw, I found a new safe value (C7) and updated my answer accordingly. Enabling C8 resulted in a reboot, so C7 should be the optimal value for now.

This is just a side note, but when trying out Windows, I found that the CPU's minimum frequency was set at 1.1GHz which is a bit higher than on Linux (0.8GHz). 0.8GHz is the supported minimum frequency specified by Intel. I tried raising the min frequency on Linux, but it still went down to 0.8GHz from time to time (probably when it went into higher c-state), and I still got the reboot. So something is done on Windows to prevent the reboot; we just don't know what it is.

Jemee Kim you are brilliant! Huge thanks for explaining the topic in detail. Such people in the community are a treasure!

Update: There's a new version of bios available on Gigabyte website. This one is a stable version unlike previous beta ones. I won't be able to try it out for a while, but I should be able to in a week or two. I'll come back and write an update after I do that.

same problem here. It has only happened to me 4 times since installation (15 days of work), I don't remember when it started or due to what update it was, but today was the last time and I started investigating. I will bring more data the next time it happens.

OS: Ubuntu 24.04 (new HW just installed)
Kernel: 6.8.0-41-generic
Motherboard: Gigabyte Z790 UD AX CPU: Intel Core i9-14900K
BIOS Version: F11d
Memory: 96GB (2x48GB) DDR5 6000MT/s / x2 Channel
Dual Boot: Not yet, but soon will install Windows

Similar messages as you above on I2C, WiFi, BT, Nvidia DRM.
Except Gnome. Nothing reported on Gnome.

Temperature is ok.
Just finished Memtest86 perfect.

Similar posts seen here and here not helping in my case.
System is pretty stable apart from this issue.

I wrote to Gigabyte about this issue and they wrote me something like this:
Since there's no issue when using the motherboard with Windows OS, the issue can rarely be the hardware issue. As we mentioned on the driver download page of the GIGABYTE website, due to different Linux support conditions provided by chipset vendors, please try to download the Linux driver from the chipset vendors' website or 3rd party website. Since we have not received the proper driver from the chipset vendor, we cannot guarantee Linux to work on our system.

So I assume we are waiting for some ubuntu or Bios update that will solve this problem.

This is not a solution then(?)
